# Oracle APEX not working on CentOS 7

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

i´ve just installed a CentOs 7 minimum server in a VM with Oracle XE.

All installation went fine but that I cannot access APEX from a remote IP (my host computer). The CentOS is minimum and I don´t have GNOME to try to access from the localhost browser.

I´ve configured remote access, as follow:

```
SQL> EXEC DBMS_XDB.SETLISTENERLOCALACCESS(FALSE);
```

Here is the listener status:

```
$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 17-JAN-2016 12:22:15

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Start Date                17-JAN-2016 11:48:31
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 33 min. 44 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC_FOR_XE)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "PLSExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "PLSExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "XE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

How can I know that the APEX is service is running ?

How can I start it up and access from a remote computer ?

Comment: Try a wget of http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex to see if it is available from the localhost. You may have a different port number. You can query that in the database SELECT dbms_xdb.gethttpport FROM dual;

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the " `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))`" in the Endpoint summary.

i.e. No listener running for apex

```
begin
   dbms_xdb.sethttpport ('8080');
end;
```

To check if it's set:

```
select dbms_xdb.gethttpport as "HTTP-Port" from dual;
```